# Docker MySQL container ERROR 1030 (HY000): Got error 168 - 'Unknown (generic) error from engine' from storage engine

Tags: mysql, docker

I created a docker container with MySQL and whenever I'm trying to create a table here is the error I have :

```
ERROR 1030 (HY000): Got error 168 - 'Unknown (generic) error from engine' from storage engine
```

The query :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ps_customer_extra` (
                        `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                        `id_customer` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                        `id_employee` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                        `position` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                        `client_code` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
                        `tva` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
                        `contact_method` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
                        `working_field` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
                        PRIMARY KEY(`id`),
                        CONSTRAINT fk_customer_extra_to_id_customer
                        FOREIGN KEY (id_customer)
                            REFERENCES ps_customer(id_customer) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
                        CONSTRAINT fk_customer_extra_to_id_employee
                        FOREIGN KEY (id_employee)
                            REFERENCES ps_employee(id_employee) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
                        ) ENGINE = INNODB default CHARSET = utf8;
```

### EDIT

```
mysql:
    image: library/mysql:8.0
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - ./.docker/data/mysql/:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./.docker/logs/mysql/:/var/log/mysql
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    container_name: presta_mysql
```

Does anyone know the reason and how to fix it? I searched but I don't find anything helpful

Comment: Have you mounted a volume to your container, that the db can actually write to?

Comment: I think I did I'll edit my post with it. However `docker volume ls` return no volume

Comment: Is this one of those instances where your hard disk is full (the mounted one), or check perms as this is a mysql error not a docker error

Comment: How could I check ? i'm trying to run the query from the container bash so I don't think this is a permission issue

Comment: Please share more details. Starting the container and running a query, doing nothing more, yields this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the way I was defining my volumes.

```
mysql:
image: library/mysql:8.0
env_file:
  - .env
volumes:
  - ./.docker/data/mysql/:/var/lib/mysql
  - ./.docker/logs/mysql/:/var/log/mysql
ports:
  - "3307:3306"
container_name: presta_mysql
```

Those lines `/.docker/data/mysql/` were creating folder containing my informations.

I just defined another volume on my `docker-compose.yml` and removed those lines by the name of my volume :

```
networks:
  prestashop:

volumes:
  db-data:
```

and :

```
volumes:
  - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
  - db-data:/var/log/mysql
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you don't have permission

first
Run this in the mysql client (or similar):

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'datadir';
```

then

```
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql/data
```